GA4GH on sequencing sample SQL schema?
I have a catalog of over 1,000 raw sequencing samples, including RNA and DNA, stored in FASTQ or CRAM formats. Along with this, I have extensive metadata for each sample, such as patient consent dates, ethics approval, sequencing technology, and the involved laboratories, all currently spread across multiple Excel files.
I'm looking to build a new SQL database to properly model and organize this metadata. However, designing the SQL schema is proving to be complex.
Is there an open standard for how to structure this kind of data? I've explored GA4GH, but despite the wealth of information on their site, I haven't found anything directly helpful. I also tried using GPT, but the generated references seemed fabricated, and the sources provided were incorrect.
